# Swift 3: Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' while using UberRides SDK

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sdk, uber-api

I'm currently developing an iOS application using Swift 3 and the UberRides SDK. According to their docs, the AppDelegate class needs to be modified to contain the following:
[UberRides SDK AppDelegate information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtJTk.png)

I did so, and here's the code I have:

```
import UIKit
import UberRides

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Handle incoming SSO Requests
    RidesAppDelegate.sharedInstance.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    // Other logic

    return true
}

@available(iOS 9, *)
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {

    let handledURL = RidesAppDelegate.sharedInstance.application(app, openURL: url as URL, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])

    if (!handledURL) {
        // Other URL parsing logic
    }

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    let handledURL = RidesAppDelegate.sharedInstance.application(application, openURL: url as URL, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)

    if (!handledURL) {
        // Other URL parsing logic
    }

    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

}

However, I am getting the error: "Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'" in this function, specifically at "options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]":

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {

    let handledURL = RidesAppDelegate.sharedInstance.application(app, openURL: url as URL, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey])

    if (!handledURL) {
        // Other URL parsing logic
    }

    return true
}
```

I am very new to Swift, and am not really sure as to how to go about solving this issue! Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Replace your open url method to this `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool { }`

Comment: @BhavinRamani Thank you so much. XCode prompted me to make a few changes to what you posted, and here's the final snippet that worked:

func application(_app: UIApplication, openURL url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]=[:]) -> Bool {
        
        let handledURL = RidesAppDelegate.sharedInstance.application(_app, openURL: url as URL, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation] as AnyObject)